# PHP curl web crawling fail suddenly

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, cloudflare

I can web crawling a newspaper web site successful before but fail today.

But I can access the web successfully by using firefox. It just happen in curl. That mean it allow my IP to access and it is not banned.

Here is the error shown by the web

> Please enable cookies.
>
> Error 1010 Ray ID: 1a17d04d7c4f8888
>
> Access denied
>
> What happened?
>
> The owner of this website (www1.hkej.com) has banned your access based
>   on your browser's signature (1a17d04d7c4f8888-ua45).
>
> CloudFlare Ray ID: 1a17d04d7c4f8888 • Your IP: 2xx.1x.1xx.2xx •
>   Performance & security by CloudFlare

Here is my code which work before:

```
$cookieMain = "cookieHKEJ.txt";  // need to use 2 different cookies since it will overwrite the old one when curl store cookie. cookie file is store under apache folder
$cookieMobile = "cookieMobile.txt";  // need to use 2 different cookies since it will overwrite the old one when curl store cookie. cookie file is store under apache folder
$agent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";

// submit a login
function cLogin($url, $post, $agent, $cookiefile, $referer) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 100);          // follow the location if the web page refer to the other page automatically
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // Get returned value as string (don’t put to screen)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);        // Spoof the user-agent to be the browser that the user is on (and accessing the php script)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);   // Use cookie.txt for STORING cookies
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                           // Tell curl that we are posting data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);            // Post the data in the array above
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);       // execute
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}    

$input = cDisplay("http://www1.hkej.com/dailynews/toc", $agent, $cookieMain);
echo $input;
```

How can I use curl to pretend the browser successfully? Did I miss some parameters?

Comment: It clearly says Access denied. You are not allowed to crawl the website without their permission and you just got banned.

Comment: But I can access the web "http://www1.hkej.com/dailynews/toc" successfully by using firefox. It just happen in curl.

Comment: Because it's blocking based on browser signature (signature is probably built from different parameters). Your default firefox has different signature than curl.

Comment: So any curl parameter I miss that I can't pretend a browser by using curl

Comment: They have banned your IP because they don't want you to crawl their website . Now to crawl the page you may have to change the ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the post, I can use firefox to access the web and my IP is not banned. 
At last, I got success after I changed the code from

```
$agent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";
```

to

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Actually, I don't know why it fail when "User-Agent: " exist start from yesterday but it is alright before.

Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The users have used Cloudflares security features to prevent you crawling their website, More than likely got shown as a malicious bot. They will have done this based on your user-agent and IP address.

Try changing your IP (if home user, try rebooting your router. sometimes will get a different IP address). Try using a proxy and try sending different headers with Curl.

More importantly they do not want people crawling their site and affecting their traffic etc, You should really ask permission for this.